# Parallel coordinates in Vega-Lite?

Tags: javascript, plot, vega-lite, parallel-coordinates

Is it possible to create parallel coordinates in [Vega-Lite](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/)? I'm looking for a simple yet powerful plotting library for JavaScript and support for parallel coordinates is a requirement.

I have [googled](https://www.google.com/search?q=vega-lite+parallel+coordinates) it but only found how to do it in [Vega](https://vega.github.io/vega/examples/parallel-coordinates/).

Comment: I've used this library before, not sure if it'll help or not: https://syntagmatic.github.io/parallel-coordinates/

Comment: @AndroidNoobie Interesting, but seems to be very restricted in functionality (it can only draw parallel coordinates)

Comment: But the underlying library (d3.js) can draw a wide range of plot types.

Comment: @AndroidNoobie d3.js is an alternative—I know it's very powerful, but I wouldn't consider it especially simple since you have to write quite a lot of code to draw a plot compared to many other visualization libraries

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can create a parallel coordinates plot in Vega-Lite by combining a window transform and a fold transform. Here is an example with the Iris dataset ([vega editor link](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAmCGAutIC4yghSBXATgGxSjkQHoBLHMgZwDoArKgewDtJwwBfAGncnh1jMqAM0Y4AtoQDa7CMEgB3Ms2iMF0+YwAOhSAGNGWZvEhcosKruXQApgA9IHALrdZaSKLzRpkLTcR4ADI2zADm8AAWplB+AQDqZNCR0ZBUNlqwQSHhUWap6ZkJSVEu7E48mOKwOADWunjKNqa8IQbQyqGE6Bj6jHhiXXwAnn66zIziypkpwmQ2XrpUfnpzlq4YRP6wZASo8vAjTaiQ45PM03mz897H1vaOFT3asCsHgwBumVhHYAAMNABmdY9Bx7YajY6nKYES5zBbHGo2IYPNyQZFgg4QqAARywgngZEQBPeTVh110nzw30c7GBikSyVQADZfr9HpAIjYyKEIiZUADWSAOEA)):

```
{
  "data": {
    "url": "data/iris.json"
  },
  "transform": [
    {"window": [{"op": "count", "as": "index"}]},
    {"fold": ["petalLength", "petalWidth", "sepalLength", "sepalWidth"]}
  ],
  "mark": "line",
  "encoding": {
    "color": {"type": "nominal", "field": "species"},
    "detail": {"type": "nominal", "field": "index"},
    "opacity": {"value": 0.3},
    "x": {"type": "nominal", "field": "key"},
    "y": {"type": "quantitative", "field": "value"}
  },
  "width": 600,
  "height": 300
}
```

[image]

Notice we use a [window transform](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/window.html) to construct an index, followed by a [fold transform](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/fold.html) to restructure the data for plotting.

Comment: Nice! Would it also be possible to add a vertical axis to each of the coordinates to that graph, like in the Vega example?

Comment: No, vega-lite only supports multiple scales in the case of faceted or concatenated plots, in which case you can't draw lines between the axes.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I think it could be useful to feature this example on the [Vega-Lite page](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/) so that there was an example that showed how to draw parallel coordinates on there, too :)

Comment: On the other hand, Vega-Lite is doesn't seem to handle parallel coordinate plots very well if they can't use multiple scales, since different coordinates may have very different distributions and hence require different affine transformations, which is not possible (or at least can't be represented) with only one scale. So perhaps a parallel coordinates example wouldn't be right.

Comment: Conclusion: I'll stick with Vega for now :)

Comment: Would that be possible to change the order of the keys on xAxis? Right now, they are following alphabet order

Answer (score 4):

Building on [@jakevdp's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54674391/866989), here is an improved version that normalizes each variables and manually draw axes with rule, text and tick marks.

Note that parallel coordinates are often useful when you have interactivity though, so there is more work to be done here.

```
{
  "data": {
    "url": "data/iris.json"
  },
  "width": 600,
  "height": 300,
  "transform": [
    {"window": [{"op": "count", "as": "index"}]},
    {"fold": ["petalLength", "petalWidth", "sepalLength", "sepalWidth"]},
    {
      "window": [
        {"op": "min", "field": "value", "as": "min"},
        {"op": "max", "field": "value", "as": "max"}
      ],
      "frame": [null, null],
      "groupby": ["key"]
    },
    {
      "calculate": "(datum.value - datum.min) / (datum.max-datum.min)",
      "as": "norm_val"
    },
    {
      "calculate": "(datum.min + datum.max) / 2",
      "as": "mid"
    }
  ],
  "layer": [{
    "mark": {"type": "rule", "color": "#ccc", "tooltip": null},
    "encoding": {
      "detail": {"aggregate": "count", "type": "quantitative"},
      "x": {"type": "nominal", "field": "key"}
    }
  }, {
    "mark": "line",
    "encoding": {
      "color": {"type": "nominal", "field": "species"},
      "detail": {"type": "nominal", "field": "index"},
      "opacity": {"value": 0.3},
      "x": {"type": "nominal", "field": "key"},
      "y": {"type": "quantitative", "field": "norm_val", "axis": null},
      "tooltip": [{
        "field": "petalLength"
      }, {
        "field": "petalWidth"
      }, {
        "field": "sepalLength"
      }, {
        "field": "sepalWidth"
      }]
    }
  },{
    "encoding": {
      "x": {"type": "nominal", "field": "key"}, 
      "y": {"value": 0}
    },
    "layer": [{
      "mark": {"type": "text", "style": "label"},
      "encoding": {
        "text": {"aggregate": "max", "field": "max", "type": "quantitative"}
      }
    }, {
      "mark": {"type": "tick", "style": "tick", "size": 8, "color": "#ccc"}
    }]
  },{

    "encoding": {
      "x": {"type": "nominal", "field": "key"}, 
      "y": {"value": 150}
    },
    "layer": [{
      "mark": {"type": "text", "style": "label"},
      "encoding": {
        "text": {"aggregate": "min", "field": "mid", "type": "quantitative"}
      }
    }, {
      "mark": {"type": "tick", "style": "tick", "size": 8, "color": "#ccc"}
    }]
  },{
    "encoding": {
      "x": {"type": "nominal", "field": "key"}, 
      "y": {"value": 300}
    },
    "layer": [{
      "mark": {"type": "text", "style": "label"},
      "encoding": {
        "text": {"aggregate": "min", "field": "min", "type": "quantitative"}
      }
    }, {
      "mark": {"type": "tick", "style": "tick", "size": 8, "color": "#ccc"}
    }]
  }],
  "config": {
    "axisX": {"domain": false, "labelAngle": 0, "tickColor": "#ccc", "title": false},
    "view": {"stroke": null},
    "style": {
      "label": {"baseline": "middle", "align": "right", "dx": -5, "tooltip": null},
      "tick": {"orient": "horizontal", "tooltip": null}
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to do this with Altair?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70341974/parallel-coordinates-in-altair/70350251#70350251

Comment: Would that be possible to change the order of the keys on xAxis? Right now, they are following alphabet order